# Windows Phone - Audio Endpoint Device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I can't seem to find this anywhere.

I want to build an Audio Endpoint device that plugs into the Windows Phone Headphone Jack.

I know I need to start with what the phone is capable of receiving and detecting.

Ultimately I would like to use already in existence libraries however I have no heartache about writing my own.

My problem is I can't find any examples of how people access the Audio input on the phone outside of the built in microphone.

Is there a library for this?

Comment: You mean application that plays special sound which controls some wicked machinery you plan to connect to that poor phone? If so, then question is, is it WP8 or WP7 device? As access to C++ with DirectX can make your idea easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect when a headset is plugged in using the VOIP capabilities in Windows Phone 8.

First in the WMAppManifest.xml file, you need to enable ID_CAP_VOIP and ID_CAP_AUDIOROUTING

Then in the App, you need to capture the event

```
AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault().AudioEndpointChanged += AudioEndpointChanged;

public void AudioEndpointChanged(AudioRoutingManager sender, object args) 
{
  var AudioEndPoint = sender.GetAudioEndpoint();
  switch (AudioEndPoint)
  {
     case AudioRoutingEndpoint.WiredHeadset:
          MessageBox.Show("Headset connected");
          break;
  }
}
```

This will enumerate from this list (no custom endpoints allowed)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.devices.audioroutingendpoint(v=vs.105).aspx

Sorry, but I can only answer the first part of your question about detecting the device, I'm not familiar with how the hardware device interfaces with the headphone jack to answer the rest.

Comment: Yeah this pretty much confirms that it's locked down. No custom hardware endpoint for me :-(